# My website is on the left top corner of the browser only on FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've been trying to fix the way my website looks on different browsers, and i finally achieved that on `IE` and `Google Chrome` but it's so ruined on `Mozilla Firefox` , it keeps appearing on the top left corner of the browser because I set every main `div` to be absolute even though I gave each one the necessary height for the image included and I set the width to be 100% at each `<div>`
Here's a copy of the code:

```
#headerofhome {
background-image: url(images/home/homepage_header.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 95px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

#container {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 497px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(images/home/homepage_container.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 95px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-attachment: scroll;
}

.footer {
background-image: url(images/home/homepage_footer.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 72px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 592px;
}
```

Comment: if you have position absolute and top:0; left:0; it will appear in the top left corner. That is the intended behaviour. are you trying to center the website in the middle of the page instead?

Comment: look into using `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: You don't happen to have a live version of the site somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

use `right` and `bottom` along with `left` and `top` and you'll achieve what you need =)